# LINQ query not showing results - LEFT join with WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq

This is my first foray into LINQ.
I still have to wrap my head around the results part, but I can't seem to get any results from this.

```
var institutions = from lots in lotsdb.NEWinstitution
                 join webs in webbitdb.tblinstitution
                 on lots.institutionid equals webs.dispenseinstid into newinsts
                 from webs2 in newinsts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where webs2 == null


                 select new
                 {
                  instid = lots.institutionid,
                  instname = lots.institutionname
                 };

        foreach(var instfound in institutions)
   {

       MessageBox.Show(instfound.instid.ToString() + " " + instfound.instname.ToString());
   }
```

I'm using Datasets created by Visual Studio in the DATASources list.

Below is my original SQL string that i have "tried" to adapt to LINQ

```
string strgetloc = @"
SELECT NEWinstitution.institutionid, NEWinstitution.institutionname
FROM NEWinstitution 
LEFT JOIN tblinstitution 
ON NEWinstitution.institutionid = tblinstitution.dispenseinstid
WHERE (((tblinstitution.institutionid) Is Null));"
```

Comment: Do you really only need the empty ones? `where webs2 == null`

Comment: I've been canabalising LINQ examples.. and I'm guessing this is incorrect. 
I want lotsdb.NEWinstitution.institutionid WHERE webbitdb.tblinstitution.institutionid IS NULL

Comment: Are you sure this query returns results at all? Have you tried running the analogous in sql server?

Comment: Well the SQL works, and this is my first try ever at writing LINQ, so I'm assuming it is wrong.. Ill post my SQL

Comment: Your SQL doesn't seem to match - why are you testing `tblinstitution.instituionid Is Null`?

Comment: I was trying to get all NewinstitutionID WHERE tblinstitutionid.instititutionid IS null.
So i end up getting all institutions in SOURCE database that are not already in my Destination Database

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this:

```
var institutions = 
    from lots in lotsdb.NEWinstitution
    join webs in webbitdb.tblinstitution on lots.institutionid equals webs.dispenseinstid
    where webs.IsInstitutionIdNull()

    select new
    {
      instid = lots.institutionid,
      instname = lots.institutionname
     };
```

The `IsInstitutionIdNull()` method is generated by the MSDataSetGenerator when the columns allows DBNull. Because you cannot compare it directly to `DBNull` or to `null`.

*(fixed a typo)*

Comment: mmm thanks for the advice.  I have to admit I'm out of my depth here and have no idea how to get the IsInstitutionIdNull() working

Comment: My other option (which I am capable of) is importing the data from LOTS to WEBS tmp table then running a normal SQL join on that... but it seems like a bad thing to do.

Comment: @GlennAngel if you open the XSD, you'll get a designer. Check the column `InstitutionId` on "Allow null". If it allows null, the generator will generate that method and you can use it in the code behind.

Comment: In the Designer for webbit data, I can see all the tables for Webbitdb, I'm very sorry but i cant see where to "allow Null" inside the tblinstitution...

Comment: ohhh ok, i found the Allow Null.  in Properties for the Institution ID.

Comment: IsInstitutionIdNull()  - How do i implement this though..  I'm sorry for all the questions but I don't actually understand what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using the following code:

```
 var idsNotInB = dtLotsInst.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("institutionid"))
    .Except(dtWebbitInst.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("institutionid")));

         count = idsNotInB.Count();

        if (count != 0)
        {
            DataTable dtOnlyLots = (from row in dtLotsInst.AsEnumerable()
                                    join id in idsNotInB
                                    on row.Field<int>("institutionid") equals id
                                    select row).CopyToDataTable();
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(PackChecker.Properties.Settings.Default["WebbitConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                string strgetloc = @"INSERT INTO tblinstitution ( dispenseinstid, institutionname ) VALUES (?,?)";

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strgetloc, con))
                {

                    con.Open();
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtOnlyLots.Rows)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dr["institutionid"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = dr["institutionname"].ToString();

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();


                    }
                    con.Close();
                }


            }
        }
```

This uses LINQ and works well by using "EXCEPT" in the first LINQ section to find values not in one table. Then it uses this list to generate the rows from the table I want.